# Acessar array de objeto dentro de um switch

Tags: java, array, switch

Boa noite, estou tendo dificuldade em acessar e modificar um array de objetos da classe main dentro de um switch na classe de visão.

O array está declarado assim no main:

```
public class Controle {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Visao umaVisao = new Visao();
    Cliente umCliente = new Cliente();
    Bebida umaBebida = new Bebida();
    Comida umaComida = new Comida();
    Funcionario umFuncionario = new Funcionario(null);


    Cliente[] array = new Cliente[100];

    umaVisao.Recepcao();
    umaVisao.NoMesasDisp();
    umaVisao.selecionarOperacao(umCliente, umFuncionario, umaVisao, umaComida, umaBebida);
```

O programa é sobre o funcionamento de um bar onde o objeto Cliente contem Nome, Mesa, pedidos etc.
E no switch de adicionar o cliente está assim:

```
public void selecionarOperacao(Cliente umCliente, Funcionario umFuncionario, Visao umaVisao, Comida umaComida, Bebida umaBebida)
  {
  String[] opcoes = {"Imprimir conta", "Cardapio", "Adicionar pedido", "Cadastrar mesa", "Alterar preços", "Quit"};
  Cliente[] arrayDeObjetos = new Cliente[100];

  while (true) {
      int resposta = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null 
                       , "Selecione a operação a ser realizada"        
                       , "Programa de Gerencimaneto do Bar"              
                       , JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION  
                       , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE  
                       , null                       
                       , opcoes                    
                       , "" 
                     );
      switch (resposta) {
          case 0: 
              umaVisao.ImprimeConta(umCliente, umaVisao);;
              break;

          case 1:

              umaVisao.Cardápio(umaComida, umaBebida);
              break;

          case 2:
              umaVisao.adicionaPedido(umCliente, umaComida, umaBebida, umaVisao, umFuncionario);
              break;

          case 3:

              int digiteAMesa = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o numero da mesa que vai cadastrar"));
              arrayDeObjetos[digiteAMesa] =  umaVisao.cadastraCliente();

              break;

          case 4:
              umaVisao.alteraprecos(umCliente, umFuncionario, umaVisao, umaComida, umaBebida);
              break;

          case -1:
              int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Deseja mesmo sair do programa? Qualquer registro será apagado.", "Sair", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
              if (result == 1){
                  break;}
                  else{                 
                   System.exit(0);
                  }

          default:
              int resultado = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Deseja mesmo sair do programa? Qualquer registro será apagado.", "Sair", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
              if (resultado == 1){
                  break;}
                  else{                 
                   System.exit(0);
                  }
      }
```

O método que adiciona cliente é esse:

```
public Cliente cadastraCliente() {

  String nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nome do Cliente: ");

  boolean maioridade = false;

  int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Existe um responsável maior de idade na mesa?", "Maioridade", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
  if (dialogResult == 0){
      maioridade = true;}
      else
    maioridade = false;

  int numeroDePessoasNaMesa = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Mesa para quantas pessoas?"));

  Cliente umCliente = new Cliente();

  return umCliente;   
  }
```

A minha duvida é sobre como eu posso criar um array de objetos (na classe principal), e pelo switch acessar esse método para adicionar um cliente.

Comment: O array está definido no mesmo escopo? É uma variável da classe? O switch está dentro dum método diferente do main? Está a inicializar a variável mais que uma vez? Tem que dar mais detalhes. Mas as perguntas que coloquei podem ajudar a resolver o problema...

Comment: Explique o erro que está tendo por favor, Osvaldo.

Comment: @BrunoCosta O array está definido na classe principal, e o switch dentro da Visao. A minha dúvida é como o switch pode alterar o array que está em outra classe. Vou postar melhor o código em outro comentário, mas muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Pablo editei a pergunta para ficar um pouco mais claro. Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: @BrunoCosta editei a pergunta para ficar um pouco mais claro. Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Onde está o switch citado?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe editei e adicionei o switch todo.

Comment: Já tentou passar o array como parametro?

Comment: Ou senão torne o array da classe controle como `public` e acesse ele assim `Controle.array`.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe passar como parametro pra acessar usando get e set? Desculpe a falta de conhecimento

Comment: @Osvaldo você quer acessar o Arraylist `array` do main no seu método `selecionarOperacao` correto? Adicione o array como parametro deste metodo também, ou torne a variavel `array` publica e acesse da forma que disse no comentario anterior.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode declarar o método da seguinte forma:

```
public void selecionarOperacao(Cliente[] array, Cliente umCliente, Funcionario umFuncionario, Visao umaVisao, Comida umaComida, Bebida umaBebida) {}
```

Você deve passar o array como parâmetro para o método.
Arrays em java também são objetos. Quando você adicionar elementos no array dentro do método selecionarOperacao, você estará alterando o mesmo array que está no main.